# How to run PageRank in Blazegraph on a dataset?

Tags: parallel-processing, bigdata, gpgpu, pagerank, blazegraph

I want to run the PageRank algorithm in Blazegraph on dataset downloaded from *SNAP*, the *Stanford Network Analysis Project*. As far as I can see, there is a PageRank implementation in Blazegraph, but I cannot find a way to run it. Is it possible to run it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Blazegraph GAS API](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/RDF_GAS_API#Running_GAS_Programs) to execute graph analytics on data loaded in Blazegraph.  The example below shows running a PageRank over all of the data loaded in a namespace.  If you have a particular SNAP data set converted to RDF, you'd like to see feel free to post a link.

```
PREFIX gas: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/gas#>
SELECT ?node ?rank {
  SERVICE gas:service {
     gas:program gas:gasClass "com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.PR" .
     gas:program gas:out ?node . # exactly once - will be bound to the visited vertices.
     gas:program gas:out1 ?rank . # Computed PageRank value for the node
  }
  FILTER (?rank<100)
} ORDER BY DESC(?rank)
```

PageRank example output over the connectivity of Autonomous System (AS) Links:

```
node    rank
<as:1120>   0.4546700227713777
<as:11492>  0.42358562655858023
<as:12644>  0.41794183515852634
<as:12143>  0.39695587975476715
<as:10217>  0.37759985273202806
<as:13092>  0.3668006144247455
<as:11139>  0.33221277719235737
<as:12722>  0.3256365110406788
<as:10913>  0.32270313230429504
```

Comment: Hi! How can I do it from a Java code? Well I'm trying to implement a algorithm but, as a start, I would like to run one of the implemented to start learning, but I don't know how. I posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261303/gas-api-implementation-and-usage Thanks!