# GAS API implementation and usage

Tags: graph-databases, blazegraph, bigdata

I'm trying to learn and use the GAS API to implement a Random Walk over my database, associating every visited vertex to the starting vertex.

I'm having some issues understanding how I can manage to do this; I've been reviewing the PATHS, BFS, PR, and other GAS classes as examples, but I'm not quite sure how to start.

I think my implementation should extend `BaseGASProgram` and implement the needed methods. Also, as iterative, the frontier contains all the vertexes of the current iteration. The concept of *predecessor* is also clear to me.

But I don't think that I understand very well the Gather, Apply, Scatter philosophy and how to distribute the Random Walk over these three concepts.

Also, once I implement my code, how do I call it? How do I even call the already implemented algorithms (PR, SSSP, BFS, etc.) inside my code? Should I instantiate an `SSSP` object and then what? Or `GASContext`? `GASRunnerBase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [TestBFS](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/blob/master/bigdata-gas/src/test/java/com/bigdata/rdf/graph/analytics/TestBFS.java) class in the bigdata-gas package:

```java
final IGASEngine gasEngine = getGraphFixture()
        .newGASEngine(1/* nthreads */);

try {

    final SailConnection cxn = getGraphFixture().getSail()
            .getConnection();

    try {

        final IGraphAccessor graphAccessor = getGraphFixture()
                .newGraphAccessor(cxn);

        final IGASContext<BFS.VS, BFS.ES, Void> gasContext = gasEngine
                .newGASContext(graphAccessor, new BFS());

        final IGASState<BFS.VS, BFS.ES, Void> gasState = gasContext
                .getGASState();

        // Initialize the froniter.
        gasState.setFrontier(gasContext, p.getMike());

        // Converge.
        gasContext.call();

[snip]
```

To use it outside of the test case context, you need to create a `SailConnection` of some sort. See the *blazegraph-samples* GitHub project for examples. Then you need to create a [`SAILGASEngine`](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/blob/master/bigdata-gas/src/main/java/com/bigdata/rdf/graph/impl/sail/SAILGASEngine.java). This should get you started in terms of calling the `GASEngine` directly at the Java layer.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I was just checking these classes; I'm going to try it out and let you know. When I got it (kind of) figured out, I'll mark your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Brad, sorry to bother you. I've managed to run the TestBFS program using the local example file. But What I'm really trying to do is to run GAS programs (testing BFS may be) against my Blazegraph remote server. I've already connected to my server and perform queries (both for selecting and inserting) using RemoteRepository. But, for using the GAS API and run GASPrograms do I still need to use a SailConnection? or is it just for working with "in-memory" on-the-fly-loaded rdf dataset?
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @aquiros: If this answer is somewhat helpful for you, then please consider accepting and/or upvoting it. If you have a substantial follow-up question, then please ask a new question. If you keep asking many questions in the comments, then you might be perceived as a help vampire that keeps on asking questions, but doesn't accept or upvote answers.

Comment: @honk thanks. I'm somewhat still working on this, but You're right. I'm gonna accept this since It was helpful in some ways